# Running a HTA file remotely using PSTools

Tags: batch-file, cmd, hta, psexec

Its almost certain that HTA files are obsolete, but i've found that they are much better than `net send` / `msg`.

I'm trying to run a HTA file on a remote machine using PSTools, but instead of it running, it brings back a broken window:[image]

Running the HTA file using CMD (locally) works perfectly though.

My PsExec line:

```
PsExec.exe -accepteula -i -d \\itwall cmd 'mstha \\intranet\Downloads\VisitorSystemNewMessage.hta asd'
```

I even tried to run the HTA from a Batch file, but the exact same thing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd try doublequotes, not single ones! I'd also use the `/C` option with `cmd`

Comment: No different, does the exact same thing :/

Comment: With /C, the hta file opens then straight away closes..

Comment: The `-i` and `-d` options are counterintuitive, one is interactive and the doesn't wait for the application to terminate _(when using non-interactive applications)_. Why do you think you'd need to run `mshta` from `cmd`? _is it a console application/tool?_

Comment: I only started using `mshta` after a quick google search, but it didnt make any difference to whether it would run or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the account running the command cannot interact with the session of the remote user.

Use the `-s` switch to run the HTA using the `system` account of the remote computer.

Also, you shouldn't need to run `cmd`. You should be able to just specify `mshta.exe` then your arguments.

```
PsExec.exe -accepteula -s -i -d \\itwall mshta.exe \\intranet\Downloads\VisitorSystemNewMessage.hta asd
```

Edit: To illustrate that this is not an HTA issue. Run the following command:

```
PsExec.exe -accepteula -i -d \\itwall notepad.exe
```

Notice you'll have the same black window showing.

Comment: This returns `PsExec could not start mstha.exe on itwall: The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: After removing the mstha.exe, your answer fixed the issue :)

Comment: My current `working` command is: `PsExec.exe -accepteula -s -i -d \\itwall cmd /c \\intranet\downloads\VisitorSystemNewMessage.hta`

Comment: I had misspelled `mshta.exe` as `mstha.exe` in my example. I went ahead and corrected the spelling.

Comment: the HTA did open but just white box. it seems it wont run any codes in it.